# Having problems with anonymous functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters, anonymous-function

```
jQuery.fn.testeee = function(_msg)
{
    alert(_msg);
    $(this[0]).overlay({ 
        onBeforeLoad: function() 
        {
            alert(_msg);
        }
    }).load();
};
$("#popup").testeee ('test');
$("#popup").testeee ('another_test');
```

This displays:

- test
- test
- another_test
- test

The alert() inside de anonymous function asigned to onBeforeLoad keeps showing "test". I try this:

```
jQuery.fn.testeee = function(_msg)
{
    alert(_msg);
    $(this[0]).overlay({ 
        onBeforeLoad: static_func(_msg)
    }).load();
};
function static_func(_msg) 
{
    alert(_msg);
}
$("#popup").testeee ('test');
$("#popup").testeee ('another_test');
```

And it works just fine. It displays:

- test
- test
- test
- test

Anybody knows why can be happening this?

Comment: What happens when you call testeee on different elements?  Perhaps overlay doesn't create a new one if there's already one on the element?

Answer (score 2):

If you create an object like this:

```
{
   onBeforeLoad: static_func(_msg)
}
```

It doesn't specify a function to call, instead it calls the function immediately and stores the return value in the object.

To specify a function to call you only use the function name:

```
{
   onBeforeLoad: static_func
}
```

If you want to call the function with a parameter that you specify yourself, you have to create a closure that contains the variable by wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
{
   onBeforeLoad: function() { static_func(_msg) }
}
```

Comment: So, why in the first example the function alert() (which is called by an anonymous function) keeps showing the first value of _msg *test* instead of showing the value that you are actually passing in the next callings (*another_test* in this case)?